# Cracking sound whenever I play a song

Tags: 12.04, speakers

I successfully installed 12.04 on my computer which also has Windows 7. All works fine other than the songs that I try to play. Whether it be through VLC, Rhythmbox or Audacious player, I get a cracking sound whenever I play songs, it stops for a few seconds, skips a few parts and altogether its a terrible experience for the ears.

On the terminal, I wrote `sudo lspci -v` as given in the "help", and below is the result I got:

```
ananyabrata@ananyabrata-desktop:~$ sudo lspci -v
[sudo] password for ananyabrata: 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset DRAM Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 5756
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: [88] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 5756
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [a0] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [140] Root Complex Link
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 5756
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f0f0 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 5756
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at e0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [130] Root Complex Link
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00001000-00001fff
    Memory behind bridge: 80200000-803fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000080400000-00000000805fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 5756
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [180] Root Complex Link
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: e0400000-e04fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000080000000-00000000801fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 5756
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [180] Root Complex Link
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 5756
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    I/O ports at f080 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 5756
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 5756
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 5756
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at f020 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 5756
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at e0504000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=32
    Capabilities: [50] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 5756

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 5756
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel modules: leds-ss4200, iTCO_wdt, intel-rng

00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01) (prog-if 8f [Master SecP SecO PriP PriO])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 5756
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at f0e0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0d0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f0c0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0b0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f0a0 [size=16]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 5756
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10
    I/O ports at 0400 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c-i801

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 5756
    Physical Slot: 0-1
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at e0424000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at e0420000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Expansion ROM at e0400000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [cc] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 90-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Two peculiar things I noticed is that I can play the songs on Windows properly and when I open YouTube, I can watch the videos without any sound problems.

Please help me out cause I'm at my wits end, I am not at all able to hear my favorite songs or watch movies and soaps.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this solution will help you:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=987252
or, maybe, this one
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio#Glitches.2C_skips_or_crackling
The latter helped me (if I don't run Skype though).